# Can I install xscreensaver on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Is it possible to install xscreensaver on Ubuntu?

I seem to have gnome-screensaver and it doesn't seem to want to work on my shiny new Dell Inspiron 15 3000-Series.

Comment: This question belongs to http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I thought that it was already installed, but you just need to remove gnome-screensaver:

http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/trusty/main/g/gnome-screensaver/en/uninstall/index.html

and then install xscreensaver:

http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/trusty/universe/x/xscreensaver/en/install/index.html

Perhaps the real question should be why it's not working for you. What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Wow, that was fast. I'm using 14.10.

Comment: If it's a bug then report it to Ubuntu I suppose. those llinkse should really be http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/utopic/main/g/gnome-screensaver/en/uninstall/index.html and http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/utopic/universe/x/xscreensaver/en/install/index.html in that case, but I don't think there's any difference. I prefer xscreensaver anyway. Good luck.